# Pass a ulong64 array from VC++ to VC# and freeing the memory

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am calling a method from C# like this:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Hash.dll",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr ph_dct_videohash(
        string file,
        ref int length);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int length = 0;
            ph_dct_videohash(@"C:\Users\shady\H.avi", ref length);
            Console.Read();

    }
```

And here is the method I am calling from the library

```
ulong64* ph_dct_videohash(const char *filename, int &Length){

CImgList<uint8_t> *keyframes = ph_getKeyFramesFromVideo(filename);
if (keyframes == NULL)
    return NULL;

Length = keyframes->size();

ulong64 *hash = (ulong64*)malloc(sizeof(ulong64)*Length);
//some code to fill the hash array
return hash;}
```

The question is how can I retrieve the unsigned 64bit Long array in C# and free the memory after using it. It would be even better if it is managed by the garbage collector for me.

I tried Marshal.copy but it didn't work and I am afraid there would be a mem leak (I don't know whether the mem will be freed automatically or not). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pass the array as an argument instead.  No memory ownership trouble and no copying required.

Comment: If I pass a pointer to the date using an argument I will still have to free it in C#, won't I? I am not sure how will this fix my problem?

Comment: No, managed memory is taken care of by the garbage collector.

Comment: Just to make sure I get the idea. I create the array in C#, pass it's pointer to the library's method which will fill the array for me and that's it?

Comment: Yes.  Be sure to pass the proper Length, overwriting the end of the array corrupts the garbage collected heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways that you can follow:

1. **Add "free" function to your library and call it explicitly for each resource allocated on library's  side.** This requires the least amount of code changes on library side, but you have to remember about freeing the memory, unless you'll create some `IDisposable` wrapper for `IntPtr` that will do the job automatically. For example, you could use this class:
2. **Change public library's functions to accept pointers to buffers instead of allocating them internally**. This potentially requires lots of changes on library side, but simplifies the code on C# side.

EDIT: as a suppliment for the first suggestion, you could use following class:

```
public class HashDllAutoPtr : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\Hash.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void ph_dct_free(IntPtr ptr);

    public HashDllAutoPtr(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        Ptr = ptr;
    }

    ~HashDllAutoPtr()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public IntPtr Ptr
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ph_dct_free(Ptr);
        }
        Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Just create an instance of it for each IntPtr result. You can then either call `Dispose` manually when you want the memory to be freed, or you can just leave it hanging and it will be picked up by GC eventually (although I don't recommend it). You can read more about disposing unmanaged data [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)